# Change style of radio buttons when selected in wpf

Tags: wpf, radio-button

I have 4 colored radio buttons that are styled like toggle buttons by using

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
```

The default styling is when a color is selected, it will change the background color to white.  I want to change that so that instead it will give it a yellow border around the color.  Any ideas how to do this?

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to affect the buttons:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter>
                   </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: You need to change the default [RadioButton ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600(v=vs.110).aspx) to what you intended. It will probably be the SelectedBackgroundColor that is by default set to #FFC5CBF9

Comment: I've tried using ControlTemplate but I may be using it wrong? See edited question for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `IsChecked` you should use `HasContent`:

```
<Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
</Trigger>
```

This is the snippet from the default template, try changing it with the one you like.
I got something working here:
With your settings:
[image: RadioButton]

Good Luck

Comment: The only problem with this is that I want to change how the button behaves when it is selected.  So I only want to have the yellow BorderBrush if they click on that option.  This way seems like it will make all of the buttons have a yellow border.

Comment: Did you tried, I didn't run the project at the time and I clicked the button before taking the screenshot.